# Kotlin Coroutines Dispatchers.IO is not creating expected threads

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I was just checking the behaviour of the Coroutine Dispatchers. So I was trying to understand how many threads each of these Dispatchers can create. To check this, I created a loop statement counting from 1 to 1_000_000.

In each loop iteration, I'm creating a coroutine with Dispatchers.IO, But when I see the output, it is not created 1_000_000 coroutines, and all these are DefaultDispatcher-worker threads, and it always stops execution in the range 40000-50000  randomly.

But when I replaced Dispatchers.IO with Dispatchers.Unconfined, it actually created all the 1_000_000 coroutines without fail and all these are created on Main thread.

So I need some help here to understand why Dispatchers.IO is failed in this case.

Dispatchers.IO:

```
fun main() {
    println("Start of main")

    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> e.printStackTrace() }

    runBlocking {
        for (i in 1..1000000) {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + CoroutineName("Dispatchers.IO")).launch(handler) {
                println("${Thread.currentThread().name}  task number is :$i")
            }
        }
    }
    println("End of main")
}
```

Dispatchers.Unconfined

```
fun main() {
    println("Start of main")

    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    runBlocking {
        for (i in 1..1000000) {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Unconfined + CoroutineName("Dispatchers.Unconfined")).launch(handler) {
                println("${Thread.currentThread().name}  task number is :$i")
            }
        }
    }
    println("End of main")
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I see the output, it is not created 1_000_000 coroutines, and
> all these are DefaultDispatcher-worker threads, and it always stops
> execution in the range 40000-50000 randomly.

The reason for this, I believe is that you're not waiting for all child coroutines to complete, and your program exits prematurely.

In the below code, `Job` instances are collected in a list named `jobs`. After the loop, `jobs.joinAll()` causes the execution to wait for all child coroutines to complete.

What is interesting, is the difference in execution time `Dispatchers.IO` vs. `Dispatchers.Unconfined`.

- **Dispatchers.IO**: Elapsed time 4.040274590s
- **Dispatchers.Unconfined**: Elapsed time 959.173375ms

When adding the suspending `delay(1)` to the loop, `Dispatchers.Unconfined` will change thread from `main` to `kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor`.

`Dispatchers.Unconfined` executes in strict sequence 1..1_000_000.

[Coroutines basics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html)

Tested on AMD 8-core, Ubuntu 20.04.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlinx.coroutines.joinAll
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlin.time.ExperimentalTime
import kotlin.time.measureTime

@OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
fun main() {

    println("Start of main")

    measureTime {
        runBlocking {

            val jobs = mutableListOf<Job>()

            repeat(1_000_000) { index ->
                jobs.add(launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    println("${Thread.currentThread().name}  task number is :${index + 1}")
                })
            }

            /** wait until child coroutines complete */
            jobs.joinAll()

            println("End of main")
        }
    }.also { duration -> println("Elapsed time: $duration") }
}
```

Comment: A good detailed explanation indeed, Now I am able to see the difference between these  two  IO and Unconfined dispatchers.  But it  seems like the IO operations are more time consuming tasks when  compare  to Unconfined.

Comment: I am just wondering what will happen if we use IO dispatcher for handling a millions of operations and forget to join all these jobs, It may pass when we test with limited records but It may cause a lot of trouble when it moved to production and  have to handle with millions of data then it may close in middle without any exception. This would be a disaster . Now i realised these IO operation are more sensitive and should be handled properly.

Comment: @HemanthKumar: In some rare cases, fire-and-forget is used (skip waiting for child coroutines), but as you experienced in your code, all child coroutines died along with your main process. But if you add some more tasks after the loop, child coroutines may have enough time to complete. So I would say: Do this by the book unless you're confident with fire-and-forget. BR